# How can I change directory directly from the windows run prompt?

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line

How can I change the current directory from the the windows `run` prompt when we initialize powershell as `powershell`. For eg: `powershell --someArgs`

Comment: You can use the `Set-Location` cmdlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Set-Location or Cd

```
Powershell.exe -noexit -Command "CD 'C:\Test\'"


Powershell.exe -noexit -Command "Set-Location 'C:\Test\'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Launch `cmd.exe` and use the builtin `start` command's `/d` flag to launch `powershell.exe` with a specific working directory:

```
cmd /c start /d "C:\working\directory\goes\here" powershell.exe
```

This will set the working directory of the `powershell.exe` *process* to `C:\working\directory\goes\here`, in turn causing PowerShell's `$PWD` to change to that directory